# $X$ and $Y$ are independent with the same distribution and we know distribution of $X + Y$. Find distribution of $X$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, fourier-transform, gamma-distribution

We are given the following task:

$X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables and have the same distribution. $U$ and $V$ are independent and $U, V \sim \Gamma(2,1)$. $X + Y$ has the same distribution as $U - V$. Find the distribution of $X$.

I have calculated that the density function of $U - V$ and $X + Y$ is equal to $f(x) = \frac{1 + |x|}{4}e^{-|x|}$. I know that distribution of $X$ is uniquely defined by the distribution of $X + Y$ because $X$ and $Y$ are independent and have the same distribution. So it would suffice to just guess the correct $X$. But I couldn't manage to guess right. Then I used Fourier transform to factorize the convolution in formula for the density function of $X + Y$ and I calculated that the density function of X is $g(x) = \frac{\pi^{1/4}}{2^{3/4}}e^{-|x|}$. But this is almost certainly an overcomplication.

What would be the easiest way to calculate the distribution of $X$ from distribution of $X + Y$?

Answer (score 0):

$U, V$are independent $\Gamma(2,1)$, so we have for the m.g.f $M_U(t)=\frac1{(1-t)^2}$ and $M_{-V}(t)=M_{V}(-t)=\frac1{(1+t)^2}$; then
$$
M_{U-V}(t)=M_{U}(t)M_{-V}(t)=\tfrac{1}{(1-t^2)^2}=M_{X+Y}(t)=M_{X}(t)M_{Y}(t)=\left(M_{X}(t)\right)^2,\;|t|<1
$$
because $X, Y$ are i.i.d.

So we have $M_X(t)=\frac{1}{1-t^2}$, and then $f_X(x)=\frac12 \operatorname e^{-|x|}$, i.e. $X\sim \textrm {Laplace}(0,1) $.

Comment: I'm not supposed to use generating functions for continuous variables as we haven't covered that in course, we only covered generating functions for discrete random variables. Is there some other simple way to solve this?

Comment: Can you use Fourier/Laplace transform?

Comment: Yes, but I have already used it (I wrote how I used it in my question). Do you have some more clever way of using than I did?

Comment: So, you have just to correct the constant before $e^{-|x|}$. Check the Fourier transform evaluation; btw mgf is the Laplace transform of pdf, and the characteristic function is the Fourier transform of pdf.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I won't however accept your answer just yet in case anyone comes up with a more simple solution than using Fourier transform. I will accept your answer if no one gives a simpler one in the following days.